# Any html I write wont appear on the browser when I use copy full path

Tags: html

I have recently begun studying html, im trying to make a small crappy website, and when I copy full path and then paste it into the browser it just gives me a blank screen. Im sorry if this is simple, but nothing I do seems to change it.
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title><strong>Stanislav Stanislavich</strong></title>
</head>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="Doomer3.jpeg" alt="Sad_Slav_Boi.jpeg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <li>Just your average IT nerd in Eastern Europe</li>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

its just not appearing, a blank screen.

Comment: If you have saved the html file on the same computer you are viewing it from you can normally see it in a browser using the address: file:///path/to/web/stuff/index.html. That assumes you called the file index.html. The path to the file needs to be absolute which means it should start with the root directory of your computer. For my Linux computer it might be file:///home/steve/Desktop/index.html Hope this helps!

Comment: There are a few errors, the `body` is missing and `li` must be inside  `ul` or `ol` or `menu`. Regardless of the errors, you should still see something. Try open the file with the browser and not copying the path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a `<body>` tag.

Everything you want to display on the page, goes in the `<body>` tag. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title><strong>Stanislav Stanislavich</strong></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="Doomer3.jpeg" alt="Sad_Slav_Boi.jpeg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <li>Just your average IT nerd in Eastern Europe</li>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
</body>
```

Comment: But omitting the and `body` tag is allowed by the HTML specifications.

Comment: I just put the code in a snippet and it does give some output so I think it is more likely to be the path he is using to get to it in the browser address bar.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a late answer but for anyone who has this question and comes across this post, I had this same problem. It was so frustrating not knowing why when copying the full path or opening the file with chrome, the browser kept coming up blank. It was until I realised all I needed to was press file and save on the programme I was using (Atom). Felt silly after, but I was used to using VScode which had a live preview and would save automatically.